Dependency couldn't resolve in kmp web wasm
I have created a kmp project from kmp wizard but when I try to include gitlive firebase dependency in common Main it does not resolve because of wasm, is there anything else to be included?
I have tried many things but I think I'm missing something

it doesn't support wasm so far, follow this thread for updates

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
